# How do I get modified recurrences of Outlook appointments in Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro in Excel that reads in all of my calendar appointments for today and calculates the total time spent in these appointments. The problem I seem to be running into is that all of my appointments are recurring appointments, and some instances have the date or the start time modified. My code is filtering, but not how I would expect it to, and I think it is because of the modified recurrences.

How do I get the details of today's recurrences only?

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNS As Object
Dim olFolder As Object
Dim olApt As Object
Dim olResults As Object
Dim olItem As Object
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim mydate, sdate, edate As Date
Dim sFilter As String
Dim i As Long
Dim dtEnd As Date



mydate = Date

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFolder = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(9)

sdate = mydate + 6 / 24
edate = mydate + 17 / 24
sFilter = "[Start] >= '" & Format(sdate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'" & " AND [Start] < '" & Format(edate, "ddddd h:nn AMPM") & "'"

olFolder.Items.IncludeRecurrences = True
olFolder.Items.Sort ("[Start]")
Set olResults = olFolder.Items.Restrict(sFilter)

Hours = 0

If olResults.Count > 0 Then
    For i = 1 To olResults.Count
        Set olItem = olResults(i)
            Hours = Hours + olItem.Duration / 60
            Debug.Print olItem.Start
    Next i
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set properties on the same collection avoiding any calls to the `Items` property:

```
Dim folderItems as Outlook.Items 
Set folderItems = olFolder.Items
folderItems.IncludeRecurrences = True
folderItems.Sort ("[Start]")
Set olResults = folderItems.Restrict(sFilter)
```